# Python. Code repeats several times because the command to execute it is different

Tags: python, refactoring, discord.py, reddit

I have patched up a Discord bot using Python and it is working fine already but there is one problem.

This code repeats itself several times, once for each category of posting and right now I have random, funny, sports, games and news, so you can see the redundancy it is and what it'll further become, if there's need to make more categories.

```py
if '!random' in messageContent:
                channel = int(chanRandom.strip('"'))
                channel = client.get_channel(channel)
                while c < 50:
                    if messageContent == '!random':
                        submission = next(x for x in randomList[sortListHot] if not x.stickied)
                        sortType   = 'Hot sorting'
                    elif messageContent == '!random top':
                        submission = next(x for x in randomList[sortListTop] if not x.stickied)
                        sortType   = 'Top sorting'
                    elif messageContent == '!random new':
                        submission = next(x for x in randomList[sortListNew] if not x.stickied)
                        sortType   = 'New sorting'
                    with open(urlFile, 'r') as urlRead:
                        if str(submission.url) not in urlRead.read():
                            await channel.send(f"{submission.url}\n{submission.title}\n<https://reddit.com{submission.permalink}>")
                            await channel.send("-------------------------")
                            with open(urlFile, 'a+') as urlWrite:
                                urlWrite.write(str(f'{submission.url}\n'))
                            c += 2
                        else:
                            print(f'{messageContent} repost: {submission.url}')
                await channel.send(sortType)
```

My idea right now is to create a list with every possible command but the problem is posting in the correct channel with the variable `channel = int(chanRandom.strip('"'))`, which changes in accord to the command used `channel = int(chanNews.strip('"'))` and so on.

There is also an issue with memory usage, because I think the bot is saving everything but there is no need to but this is something for another time.

Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be using message.content for commands anymore. Please use commands. You can use a command group to make similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the contents of all the variables here, but if you want to cut down on code repition, I'd recommend making a dictionary and mapping different variables to the user input.

Here is the idea of it:

```
my_mapping = {
    "!random": (sortListHot, "Hot sorting"),
    "!random top": (sortListTop, "Top sorting"),
    "!random new": (sortListNew, "New sorting")
}

sorting_type = my_mapping[messageContent.lower()][0]  # sortListHot/Top/New
sorting_text = my_mapping[messageContent.lower()][1]  # "Hot/Top/New sorting"

submission = next(x for x in randomList[sortingType] if not x.stickied)
```

Having these mapped to a dictionary will also allow for more entries to be added easily and flexibly (just add a new key with the value being a tuple following the current pattern).

The `.lower()` was added for case insensitivity.

I can also recommend looking into command decorators instead of using the `on_message` event.

---

### References:

- [Dictionaries in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
- [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)
- [`commands.Command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) - Highly recommend switching to this.

Comment: Thank you! Got a little mode fiddling to do but this seems like it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Diggy., I was able to complete the code. This is the new version:

```py
messageContentTop = str.replace(messageContent, ' top','')
            messageContentNew = str.replace(messageContent, ' new', '')

            if messageContent or messageContentTop or messageContentNew in multiCom:
                if 'top' in messageContent:
                    channel = int(multiCom[messageContentTop][3])
                elif 'new' in messageContent:
                    channel = int(multiCom[messageContentNew][3])
                else:
                    channel = int(multiCom[messageContent][3])

                channel = client.get_channel(channel)
                while c < 50:
                    if 'new' and 'top' not in messageContent:
                        submission = next(x for x in multiCom[messageContent][4] if not x.stickied)
                        sortType   = 'Hot sorting'
                    elif 'top' in messageContent:
                        submission = next(x for x in multiCom[messageContentTop][5] if not x.stickied)
                        sortType   = 'Top sorting'
                    elif 'new' in messageContent:
                        submission = next(x for x in multiCom[messageContentNew][6] if not x.stickied)
                        sortType   = 'New sorting'
                    with open(urlFile, 'r') as urlRead:
                        if str(submission.url) not in urlRead.read():
                            await channel.send(f"{submission.url}\n{submission.title}\n<https://reddit.com{submission.permalink}>")
                            await channel.send("-------------------------")
                            with open(urlFile, 'a+') as urlWrite:
                                urlWrite.write(str(f'{submission.url}\n'))
                            c += 2
                        else:
                            print(f'{messageContent} repost: {submission.url}')
                await channel.send(sortType)
```

The `multiCom` (multiple commands, I'll think of a better name) dictionary is setup like this:

```py
multiCom = {
    '!random':  ('!random',  '!random top',  'random new',   randomChan,  reddit.subreddit(randomSubs).hot(),  reddit.subreddit(randomSubs).top(),  reddit.subreddit(randomSubs).new()),
    '!funny':   ('!funny',   '!funny top',   '!funny new',   funnyChan,   reddit.subreddit(funnySubs).hot(),   reddit.subreddit(funnySubs).top(),   reddit.subreddit(funnySubs).new()),
    '!news':    ('!news',    '!news top',    '!news new',    newsChan,    reddit.subreddit(newsSubs).hot(),    reddit.subreddit(newsSubs).top(),    reddit.subreddit(newsSubs).new())
}
```

`randomChan`, `funnyChan`, `newsChan` are variables storing the server's channels IDs.

Cleaned up about 20kb from the old version and it is noticeably faster!

Answer (score 1):

If you have code that does not fit a simple pattern and want to use a structure similar to a switch/case statement, you can write a helper function that will simulate it:

```
 def switch(value): yield lambda *match: value in match
```

Usage example:

```
 for case in switch(messageContent):

     if   case('!random'):
          submission = next(x for x in randomList[sortListHot] if not x.stickied)
          sortType   = 'Hot sorting'

     elif case('!random top'):
          submission = next(x for x in randomList[sortListTop] if not x.stickied)
          sortType   = 'Top sorting'

     elif case('!random new'):
          submission = next(x for x in randomList[sortListNew] if not x.stickied)
          sortType   = 'New sorting'
```